# Quartz - Restart Scheduler

Tags: java, mysql, jboss, cluster-computing, quartz-scheduler

I am using Quartz Scheduler (v2.2.1) in some Java WARs and I am having some trouble while recovering from database errors. The WARs are deployed in JBOSS AS 7.1.

In the initialization of the WAR, I start two schedulers: the first one configured with **JobStoreTX** as **clustered** (the WARs are deployed in a cluster) and the second one, configured with **RAMJobStore** in order to monitor some server specific settings.

The RAM Scheduler also includes a Job which monitors a table from a **MySQL** database. In case of error, it would be desirable to keep the Quartz jobs firing, but the fact is sometimes the Scheduler is frozen and these jobs are not fired.

For instance, I used the following method in my tests, with no luck re-instantianting the scheduler:

```
/**
 * Resets all scheduled jobs.
 */
public void reset(final long currentTime) {

    try {
        final StdSchedulerFactory schedFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        schedFactory.initialize("quartz.properties");
        Scheduler myScheduler = schedFactory.getScheduler();

        if (myScheduler != null) {                
            myScheduler.clear();                
            myScheduler.shutdown(); --> HERE, THE THREAD IS LOCKED !!!                
            myScheduler = null;
        }

        myScheduler = schedFactory.getScheduler();
        loadJobs(myScheduler);
        myScheduler.start();
        //myScheduler.startDelayed(10);                        

    } catch (SchedulerException e) {
        LOG.error("Scheduler error !!!");
    }
}
```

Which is the proper method to restart a Quartz Scheduler?

Thanks in advance

**UPDATE 1**

As the Scheduler object seems to be the same...I modified the method, with no luck, re-instantiating the StdSchedulerFactory and the Scheduler before calling shutdown.

Could you provide any functional example?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

saying the scheduler was frozen would mean the API has a huge bug. Could you please provide stack trace or any errors thrown in the case you are mentioning.

based on my experience scheduler object returned will be same as many times you call

> schedFactory.getScheduler();

you may need to clean up old jobs, de-reference them or stop them.

Correct steps would be

> -1- fetch the scheduler object
>
> -2- stop the scheduler by calling to scheduler.shutdown();
>
> -3- load the jobs again and start the scheduler

Comment: I also tried to call shutdown. If you look into my code it is commented, as the application got stuck at that point :(  I tried several things with no luck... I cannot provide a stack trace because I do not detect any WARNs or ERRORS (my logging system has WARN level).

Answer (score 0):

Use quartz JMX options and that MBean have operations like `start()` , `shutdown()` and `clear()` etc. making lives real simpler.